# .persist() does not work in Spring Roo in a new Thread

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading, hibernate, spring

I have a standard Spring Roo (1.2.0.RC1) project with standard domain objects. In my main thread (a domain controller), I can create instances of domain objects backed by the database (I am using Hibernate / MySQL) using a finder, change some properties and persist the changes back to the DB by calling .persist() on the instances to be saved.

If I move this entire logic to a Runnable and execute it in a new Thread (invoked by ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate()), I can still properly create the instances of the domain objects using the finder, but changing some properties and calling .persist() on the objects to be saved has no effect on the DB. I don't see anything in the console log (running inside of STS). I don't know if there are any other log files that Roo creates that could give me additional clues as to what might be going on. Has anyone else experienced the aforementioned issue? Does anyone know how to get more verbose logging in the STS console (such as Hibernate query logging) for Roo?

Comment: Show us code. And be aware that a Hibernate Session is a single-threaded object, and that the transactional context relies on ThreadLocal variables.

Comment: Add hibernate property show-sql to persistence.xml for more information

Comment: Yes, the Hibernate Session is typically stored as a ThreadLocal variable - so objects that you create in the new thread do not have a Hibernate Session.

Comment: ok, that makes sense, but why do finders (resulting in SELECT queries) work in the new thread? Also, is there a workaround for the new thread to get access to the Hibernate Session?

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with the Transaction.  The default in Hibernate, or JTA for that matter, is to use local transactions, which are bound to the thread.  Really, you shouldn't try to share transactions across threads.  Whatever objects you're sharing between threads (the hibernate session?) I bet they're not actually thread safe.

I would try to simplify your code and not process updates in multiple threads.  If you MUST use multiple threads, they'll have to each have their own transactions.

Chances are, you just need a new transaction for each thread.  But that's why you can select data from your threads, but you can't persist.  It sounds like the transactions inside your threads aren't being closed.